# find exact value of $\cos^{-1}(\cos(9\pi/7))$

Tags: functions, inverse

anybody know how to find the exact value of $\cos^{-1}(\cos(\frac{9\pi}7))$ using inverse functions without the use of a calculator, i have no idea how to use $\frac{9\pi}7$ or how to get it to a term on the unit circle. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $\dfrac{9\pi}{7}$ is slightly more than half a circle
- $\cos\left(\pi+\theta\right)=\cos\left(\pi - \theta\right)$
- There is some $\phi$ for which $\cos^{-1} (\cos \phi)=\phi$

Comment: how would you get 5pi/7 from 9pi/7? ?

Comment: I'm guessing OP is just learning trigonometry so this solution may be out of reach.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $P\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right) = (u,v)$ so that
$u = \cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)$ and 
$v = \sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)$

Note that $\pi - \dfrac{2\pi}{7} = \dfrac{5\pi}{7}$, so 
$P\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{7}\right)=(-u,v)$ and is in the second quadrant.

It follows that 
$\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{9\pi}{7}\right)\right)
 = \cos^{-1}(-u) = \dfrac{5\pi}{7}$

You can verify this by showing that

\begin{align}
   \cos\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{7}\right) 
   & = \cos\left(\pi - \dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right) \\
   & = \cos(\pi) \cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right) 
      -\sin(\pi) \sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)\\
   &=-\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{7}\right)\\
   &= -u
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Just like the tan problem you posted before, inverses cancel. Therefore, you should get $9\pi/7$

Comment: Except it's not unique. Also some people define $cos^{-1}$ to be *the* inverse of $cos$ with values in a particular range, e,g $[-\pi,\pi]$.